# why does it say that class myPair has no member of out? it works well when I define the function in the class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myPair {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    myPair(int x = 3, int y = 2) {};
    friend void out(string a) {};
};

void out(string a) {
    myPair p;
    cout << a << "x equals " << p.x << "and " << a << "y equals " << p.y;
};

int main() {
    myPair A(5, 3);
    A.out("A : ");
}
```

this code is supposed to print out info about myPair class object but for some reason compiler tells me that there is not any member with the name of out() in myPair

Answer (score 2):

You declare a function `friend` to the class so that this function can access the private data members of the class. And remember you cannot call `friend` function like `A.out` as it just an external function with special privileges and does not have `this` pointer. So it cannot be called that way.

And further, when you put `{}` in the front of the function signatures it becomes a definition. So You have to obey ODR(One Definition Rule). While declaring the friend function you cannot put `{}` otherwise you will get an error.

One more thing your constructor is not constructing the object properly, it is just taking parameters and doing nothing.

To let your friend do something to an object is to pass the object in the friend function.

You can see below the correct version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myPair {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    myPair(int _x = 3, int _y = 2): x(_x), y(_y) {};
    friend void out(const string& a, myPair& p);
};

void out(const string& a, myPair& p) {
    //myPair p;
    cout << a << "x equals " << p.x << "and " << a << "y equals " << p.y;
};

int main() {
    myPair A(5, 3);
    out("A : ", A);
}
```

This is not a method, so You need to pass your object into `out("", myPair)`. It works as expected.

Comment: Yes there is no undefined behaviour here. The use of a `friend` to circumvent encapsulation is dubious of course, but I imagine that could the unavoidable consequence of using a `friend` declaration on which, perhaps, the exercise insists. Have an upvote in other words.

Comment: One more thing, pass the `std::string` by const-reference in case it's something like a base64 encoding of a high resolution image ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, maybe he is intended to use it like `<<` operator. But It is unclear what he wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of your code is undefined. This is because you don't set the member variables in `myPair` and then subsequently read their values.

Rather than your `out` function, it's idiomatic C++ to define the `<<` operator for `ostream` and your class. In that way you can use it directly in a `cout` statement. Here are the changes, including the fix to your constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

class myPair {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    myPair(int x = 3, int y = 2) : x(x), y(y) /*there is no ambiguity here bizarrely*/
    {
    };
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const myPair& p);
};
    
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const myPair& p){
    os << "x equals " << p.x << " and y equals " << p.y;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    myPair A(5, 3);
    std::cout << "A: " << A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `out` as a friend function not a member. So your code should look like,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myPair {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    myPair(int x = 3, int y = 2) : x(x), y(y){};
    void out(string);
};

void myPair::out(string a) {
    cout << a << "x equals " << this->x << "and " << a << "y equals " << this->y;
};

int main() {
    myPair A(5, 3);
    A.out("A : ");
}
```

If you want friend functions you can do,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myPair {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    myPair(int x = 3, int y = 2) : x(x), y(y) {};
    friend void out(myPair p, string a);
};

void out(myPair p, string a) {
    cout << a << "x equals " << p.x << "and " << a << "y equals " << p.y;
};

int main() {
    myPair A(5, 3);
    out(A, "A : ");
}
```

Comment: If I've answered your question kindly accept the answer

Comment: I'm sure the OP would if it was correct. It isn't. All you are doing is outputting the information about the locally declared `myPair` instance, which doesn't initialise the member data. Which you then read. So the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Comment: @Bathsheba and I guess OP is trying to learn about friend functions.

Comment: @foragerDev: Indeed, and an answer containing undefined behaviour is not really going to be of much use.

Comment: @Bathsheba merely being able to help OP compiling the code is not enough.

Comment: No, it isn't. Why do you have a locally declared `myPair` instance in `out`? Also, your constructor does not initialise `x` and `y`.

Comment: @ShreyanAvigyan nope still printing the locally declared `p`. which is undefined.

Comment: @foragerDev: `myPair A(5, 3);` doesn't set the member data either, but I have a feeling you know that. Well you clearly do, given your answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba see my answer, I pointed it out.

Comment: Ok. Now I changed the code. This should work

Comment: No. Still undefined behaviour. See the other answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba Why?

Comment: "Also, your constructor does not initialise x and y."  You need to use your line by line debugger.

Comment: Did you check that it compiled? ;-)

Comment: Now it should compile

Comment: I've checked it

Comment: Phew. Now I can remove my downvote. Finally, you ought to pass the objects by `const` reference, especially the `std::string`. Then remove `using namespace std;`, which never appears in production code.